# Init build environment within a batch

Tags: batch-file, build-automation, vxworks

I'm using a windows batch file to run vxWorks build.
In order to run the build, I need to run the wrenv.exe utility that set up the build environment.

I'm trying the following, but the update operation fails

> call C:\WindRiver32\wrenv.exe -p vxworks-6.8
>   call wrws_update.bat -data "%WORKSPACE%" -l %APP_MODULE% -b build -c %CPU%

How can I force the batch to "remember" the wrenv.exe settings?

Answer (score 1):

The two commands may be combined, like this:

```
call C:\WindRiver32\wrenv.exe -p vxworks-6.8 wrws_update.bat -data %WORKSPACE% -l %APP_MODULE% -b build -c %CPU%
```

This will run the command "wrws_update.bat -data %WORKSPACE% -l %APP_MODULE% -b build -c %CPU%", inside the "C:\WindRiver32\wrenv.exe -p vxworks-6.8" shell, returning control upon completion.

Comment: When putting this in PowerShell script i'm getting: cannot execute command: wrws_update